# How to repeat some part of header data in every page header in RDLC?

Tags: winforms, rdlc

I am very new to RDLC report. I am working on a windows application where i have a scenario to display all header
details in the first page and only some specified data from the second page. 
Ex: I have to display district name, taluk name and hobli name in first page but only hobli name(district and taluk name should not be displayed) in/from second page header. How can i achieve this? If this is not possible in RDLC then is there any other reporting type that i can work on? Thank you. (I am using stored procedures to get the data.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Are each of these pieces of data on separate rows in the report, or are you putting together a single header line?

If they're each on their own header line, what you can do is make three nested groups, so you'll basically get:

```
<TablixMember>
  <Group><Expression>Fields!District.Value</Expression></Group>
  <TablixMembers>
    <TablixMember> 
      <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup> 
      <RepeatOnNewPage>false</RepeatOnNewPage> 
    </TablixMember>
    <TablixMember>
      <Group><Expression>Fields!Taluk.Value</Expression></Group>
      <TablixMembers>
        <TablixMember> 
          <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup> 
          <RepeatOnNewPage>false</RepeatOnNewPage> 
        </TablixMember>
        <TablixMember>
          <Group><Expression>Fields!Hobli.Value</Expression></Group>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember> 
              <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup> 
              <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage> 
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
               <Group Name="Detail" />
               <TablixMembers>
                 <TablixMember />
               </TablixMembers>
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixMember>
      </TablixMembers>
    </TablixMember>
  </TablixMembers>
</TablixMember>
```

and only the last header row will repeat on a new page.